# purrr solution for a for loop over two groups of vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

I am looking for a purrr solution to accomplish what I have done with a for loop. I suspect it will be a version of map2 or pmap. I've looked at the documentation and it makes sense for the simple cases provided, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use this for my case.

In the data frame below, the "Sum" columns contain monthly forecast for a given SKU. The "End of" columns contain the month-end date for the given month. The rule I am applying is that if the year (last two digits in the End of columns) is greater than 22, I replace the corresponding values in the Sum column for the given month/SKU with 0. The code I currently use (which works) is below.

```
sample.data.frame <- data.frame(SKU = c('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'), 
'Sum Month 01' = c(3, 9, 8), 'Sum Month 02' = c(5, 10, 4), 
'Sum Month 03' = c(9, 6, 5), 'Sum Month 04' = c(5, 9, 10), 
'End of Month 01' = rep('10/28/22', 3), 
'End of Month 02' = rep('12/02/22', 3), 
'End of Month 03' = rep('12/30/22', 3), 
'End of Month 04' = rep('01/27/23', 3), check.names = F)

for (i in seq_along(sample.data.frame[grepl("Sum Month", colnames(sample.data.frame))])){
    if (substr(sample.data.frame[grepl("End of", colnames(sample.data.frame))][[i]][[1]], 7, 8) > 22){
      sample.data.frame[grepl("Sum Month", colnames(sample.data.frame))][[i]] <- 0
    }
  
}
```

Additionally, I have written the following function based on the code above which works on a vector of dates and a vector of numbers. I can't figure out how to make it work over multiple vectors of dates and numbers (e.g., the various columns of the dataframe).

```
data.replace.fcn <- function(date.col, number.col){
  for (i in seq_along(date.col)) {
  if (substr(date.col[i], 7, 8) > 22) {
    number.col[i] <- 0
  } else {
    number.col[i] <- number.col[i]
     
  }
    
  }
  return(number.col)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map2` from `purrr` here operating on `"Sum Month"` and `"End of"` column in pairs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2_df(select(sample.data.frame, starts_with('Sum Month')), 
        select(sample.data.frame, starts_with('End of')), 
        ~if_else(substr(.y, 7, 8) > 22, 0, .x))

#   `Sum Month 01` `Sum Month 02` `Sum Month 03` `Sum Month 04`
#           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#1              3              5              9              0
#2              9             10              6              0
#3              8              4              5              0
```

The same can be written in base R, using `mapply`/`Map` :

```
sum_month <- grep('Sum Month', names(sample.data.frame))
end_month <- grep('End of', names(sample.data.frame))

sample.data.frame[sum_month] <- Map(function(x, y) 
               ifelse(substr(y, 7, 8) > 22, 0, x), 
                sample.data.frame[sum_month], sample.data.frame[end_month])
```

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative to purrr, you could try to tranpose your data first into a tidy format? Then it would be just an if_else statement to get what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

# using your input data.frame
sample.data.frame %>% 
  
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -SKU,
    names_to = c(".value", "Month"),
    names_pattern = "(.*) (\\d\\d)",
    names_transform = list(Month = readr::parse_integer),
    values_transform = list(`End of Month` = lubridate::mdy, `Sum Month` = as.integer)
  ) %>% 
  
  mutate(`Sum Month` = if_else(lubridate::year(`End of Month`) > 2022, 0L, `Sum Month`))
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am familiar with tidy data, but given how subsequent parts of the program for which i use this file are constructed (probably not in the most efficient way, in hindsight), in this case it is probably easier to keep the data in the wide, not tidy format. This is certainly useful info, though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to transform the data into a *tidy* format (each variable is a column, each observation is a row), for which most functions in the `tidyverse` are designed:

```
library(tidyverse)
sample.data.frame_long <- sample.data.frame %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("Sum Month"), starts_with("End of Month")),
               names_to = c(".value", "Month"),
               names_pattern =  "(\\w+).*?(\\d+)")
sample.data.frame_long
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    SKU   Month   Sum End     
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 ABC   01        3 10/28/22
#>  2 ABC   02        5 12/02/22
#>  3 ABC   03        9 12/30/22
#>  4 ABC   04        5 01/27/23
#>  5 DEF   01        9 10/28/22
#>  6 DEF   02       10 12/02/22
#>  7 DEF   03        6 12/30/22
#>  8 DEF   04        9 01/27/23
#>  9 GHI   01        8 10/28/22
#> 10 GHI   02        4 12/02/22
#> 11 GHI   03        5 12/30/22
#> 12 GHI   04       10 01/27/23
```

Once this is done it is a lot easier to compare the two variables:

```
sample.data.frame_long %>% 
  mutate(Sum = ifelse(
    as.numeric(str_extract(End, "\\d+$")) > 22, 0, Sum))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    SKU   Month   Sum End     
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 ABC   01        3 10/28/22
#>  2 ABC   02        5 12/02/22
#>  3 ABC   03        9 12/30/22
#>  4 ABC   04        0 01/27/23
#>  5 DEF   01        9 10/28/22
#>  6 DEF   02       10 12/02/22
#>  7 DEF   03        6 12/30/22
#>  8 DEF   04        0 01/27/23
#>  9 GHI   01        8 10/28/22
#> 10 GHI   02        4 12/02/22
#> 11 GHI   03        5 12/30/22
#> 12 GHI   04        0 01/27/23
```

Or converting to a proper date first:

```
sample.data.frame_long%>% 
  mutate(End2 = lubridate::mdy(End)) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = ifelse(End2 > "2022-12-31", 0, Sum))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    SKU   Month   Sum End      End2      
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>    <date>    
#>  1 ABC   01        3 10/28/22 2022-10-28
#>  2 ABC   02        5 12/02/22 2022-12-02
#>  3 ABC   03        9 12/30/22 2022-12-30
#>  4 ABC   04        0 01/27/23 2023-01-27
#>  5 DEF   01        9 10/28/22 2022-10-28
#>  6 DEF   02       10 12/02/22 2022-12-02
#>  7 DEF   03        6 12/30/22 2022-12-30
#>  8 DEF   04        0 01/27/23 2023-01-27
#>  9 GHI   01        8 10/28/22 2022-10-28
#> 10 GHI   02        4 12/02/22 2022-12-02
#> 11 GHI   03        5 12/30/22 2022-12-30
#> 12 GHI   04        0 01/27/23 2023-01-27
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am familiar with tidy data, but given how subsequent parts of the program for which i use this file are constructed (probably not in the most efficient way, in hindsight), in this case it is probably easier to keep the data in the wide, not tidy format. This is certainly useful info, though.